# Handling null in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java

With the upcoming [RxJava2 release](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/tree/2.x) one of the important changes is that `null` is no longer accepted as a stream element, i.e. following code will throw an exception: `Observable.just(null)`

Honestly, I have mixed feelings about this change and part of me understands that it will enforce clean APIs, but I can see a number of use cases when this might be a problem.

For instance, in my app I have an in-memory cache:

```
@Nullable CacheItem findCacheItem(long id);
```

CacheItem might not be present in cache, so method might return null value.

The way it is used with Rx* - is as following:

```
Observable<CacheItem> getStream(final long id) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<CacheItem>() {
        @Override public CacheItem call() throws Exception {
            return findCacheItem(id);
        }
    });
}
```

So with this approach, I might get null in my stream which is totally valid situation, so it is handled properly on receiving side - let's say UI changes its state if item is not present in cache:

```
Observable.just(user)
          .map(user -> user.getName())
          .map(name -> convertNameToId(name))
          .flatMap(id -> getStream(id))
          .map(cacheItem -> getUserInfoFromCacheItem(cacheItem))
          .subscribe(
              userInfo -> {
                  if(userInfo != null) showUserInfo();
                  else showPrompt();
              }
          );
```

With RxJava2 I am no longer allowed to post `null` down the stream, so I either need to wrap my CacheItem into some other class and make my stream produce that wrapper instead or make quite big architectural changes.

Wrapping every single stream element into nullable counterpart doesn't look right to me.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

It seems like the situation like mine is quite popular, so Im curious what is the recommended strategy to tackle this problem given new "no null" policy in RxJava2?

**EDIT**
Please see follow-up conversation in [RxJava GitHub repo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4644)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to represent what you want.

One option is to use `Observable<Optional<CacheItem>>`:

```
Observable<Optional<CacheItem>> getStream(final long id) {
  return Observable.defer(() -> {
    return Observable.just(Optional.ofNullable(findCacheItem(id)));
  });
}

public static <T> Transformer<Optional<T>, T> deoptionalize() {
  return src -> 
      src.flatMap(item -> item.isPresent()
             ? Observable.just(item.get())
             : Observable.empty();
}
```

You then use `.compose(deoptionalize())` to map from the optional to the non-optional Observable.

Answer (score 2):

As another solution you can add static instance CacheItem.NULL, and return it to subscriber when there is no cached data

```
Single
    .concat(loadFromMemory(), loadFromDb(), loadFromServer())
    .takeFirst { it != CachedItem.NULL }
    .subscribe(
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RxJava2-Nullable`](https://github.com/XDean/RxJava2-Nullable) to handle null value in RxJava2.

For your situation, you can do:

```
Observable<CacheItem> getStream(final long id) {
    return RxNullable.fromCallable(() -> findCacheItem(id))
                     .onNullDrop()
                     .observable();
}
```

To invoke `showPrompt` when it's null, you can do:

```
Observable.just(user)
          .map(user -> user.getName())
          .map(name -> convertNameToId(name))
          .flatMap(id -> getStream(id).onNullRun(() -> showPrompt()))
          .map(cacheItem -> getUserInfoFromCacheItem(cacheItem))
          .subscribe(userInfo -> showUserInfo());

NullableObservable<CacheItem> getStream(final long id) {
    return RxNullable.fromCallable(() -> findCacheItem(id)).observable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to use `Maybe.switchIfEmpty`

Example:

```
public static <T> Maybe<T> maybeOfNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? Maybe.empty() : Maybe.just(value);
}

maybeOfNullable(user)
        .map(user -> user.getName())
        .map(name -> convertNameToId(name))
        .flatMap(id -> getStream(id))
        .map(cacheItem -> getUserInfoFromCacheItem(cacheItem))
        // perform another action in case there are no any non null item emitted
        .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromAction(() -> showPrompt()))
        .subscribe(userInfo -> showUserInfo());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Nulls` are weird things. From one side, they do not mark a full success, like a concrete value does. From the other side, they don't signal a complete failure like `Exception` does. So one can say that `null` is halfway between happy path and failure path. Whenever `null` is forbidden it pressures you to "make up your mind" and move it to one of the groups. Either make it a full-blown success (by wrapping it into some kind of object and putting the null handling logic into this object) or a complete error and throw it as an `Exception`.

To me it turned out very beneficial to limit the happy path to full success and handle all deviations in the `onError` channel:

```
Observable.just(user)
      .map(user -> user.getName())
      .map(name -> convertNameToId(name))
      .flatMap(id -> getStream(id))
      .map(cacheItem -> getUserInfoFromCacheItem(cacheItem)) //throws custom exception
      .subscribe(
          userInfo -> {
              showUserInfo(userInfo);
          },
          ex -> {
              showPrompt(ex); //handles the custom exception
          }
      );
```

The best part is that `onError` short-circuits all the transforms (which usually depend on the value being non-null) all the way to the point when you decide you can handle it. Being it either in `subscribe/onError` at the end or `onErrorResumeNext` somewhere in the middle of the chain. Keep in mind thought that allowing `onError` to propagate all the way terminates the chain.