# RxJava : Creating observable from a Nullable object

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava. I have a code like this. I'm creating an observable from a string  returned from `repository.getStatus()`. if it is null , I have to proceed with the `proceed` method without doing anything. If it is not null ,  I have to call `repository.init()` and then `proceed`. Here's what I have done.

```
Flowable.just(repository.getStatus()) // getStatus return a string , which can be null
        .doOnError(throwable -> proceed())
        .flatMapCompletable(s -> repository.init())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete() {
                           proceed();
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                            handleErrors(t));
                       }
                  });

private void proceed(){
    // 
}
```

In case `repository.getStatus()` is null , wont it call the `doOnError(throwable -> proceed())`? 
Now it is crashing when `repository.getStatus()` is null. What is the best Rx way to deal with this kind of a usecase?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781420/handling-null-in-rxjava2)

Comment: @masp but as told in the accepted answer , `Optional.ofNullable` required API 24 above. My min version is 19

Comment: Apart from the answer there is also a [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4644) in the question to a conversation from which you can understand a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of piping `repository.getStatus()` with `repository.init()` , you could just create an observable from any of these two based on your condition.

Try something like this

```
    Flowable.just(repository.getStatus() == null ? Completable.complete() : repository.init())
            .flatMapCompletable(c -> c)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                     handleErrors(t));
                }
            });
```

You could even make your `repository.getStatus()` as a MayBe and do something like this

```
Maybe.create((MaybeOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
        if (repository.getStatus() != null) e.onSuccess(repository.getStatus());
        e.onComplete();
    }).flatMapCompletable(s -> Completable.fromAction(() -> repository.init()))
            .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    handleErrors(t));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Rx2, you can use the new `Maybe` type, which is the streaming equivalent of `Optional`. Unfortunately, it does not have a `fromNullable` factory method (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5019), but you can use this:

`Maybe.fromCallable(() -> repository.getStatus())`