# Maybe.fromCallable{}.subscribeOn() nullability issue?

Tags: intellij-idea, rx-java2

In the following code

```
 Maybe.fromCallable { Unit.takeIf { false} }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Idea notes result of `subscribeOn` as `Maybe<Unit?>`. Though `fromCallable<Unit>` fixes it.

Is this IDE issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling null in RxJava2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781420/handling-null-in-rxjava2)

Comment: No, that question is about using (or simulate usage) nulls in RxJava. My question is more specific.

Comment: I think it has to do with this: `fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T?`. As you can see, the return element `T?` can be nullable.